# Any tool to diagnose time being taken by WebLogic Server during startup?

Tags: weblogic

Our WebLogic  Server takes 1 hr to startup using Jrockit JVM. It is pure Java EE app. 
Is there any tool we can use to diagnose why it’s taking so long to start?

Comment: What does the logs show? Also are you starting up with your app deployed? How long does a plain WLS on JRockit without you app take? There could be many reasons including less RAM etc

Answer (score 0):

Is it Linux or Windows machine?
If it's Linux machine, you try to strace it. Ie `strace -f -p <PID>` and see where it's hanging. It can be due to many reasons, eg maybe because it's waiting for a DB connection.

But, I got a feeling that it may be due to the Persistence Filestore read during startup. That operation can be very slow if the file is very large. So, you may want to check your persistence filestore especially under `<DOMAIN_NAME>/server/<SERVER_NAME>/data/store/defaults` and other filestore from `config/config.xml`.

If they are too big, compact them (check the Oracle doc) or just delete them (if its not an important env & you are lazy)

Thanks.